# Adding rows in attribute table together using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: attribute-table, arcgis-pro, statistics

I am using a parcel map and I have a layer with a ton of polygons and those polygons have different names. I combined all the names into categories in the symbology tab but when I go to the attribute table for that layer the ones I combined are no longer combined like in the symbology. I don't want to merge these polygons because I want to be able to count how many polygons are in the categories but I want the rows in the attribute table combined into the groups I put them in in the symbology.

I am using ArcGIS Pro

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the Question to specify the software in use and what you have attempted.

Comment: @Becca, is it ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Its is ArcGIS Pro

Comment: Have you looked at the Summary Statistics tool?

Comment: @PolyGeo They are different names. So like A, B, and C are one category so I need to combine them but they are different names.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we must remember that each row in the attribute table is associated with a feature on the map, and symbology is a layer property that is followed only until the layer is in the contents pane in ArcGIS Pro.

- What you can try is using the "show count" property while applying symbology

[image]

- Your aim is to get it as a table showing the count, use the summarize option to get a table representing the count of all the categorized features

[image]

- Count

[image]

- Finally, as an alternative, if you want a group symbology("not the attributes") follow the [Group Unique Values](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000017852) link for a better understanding